# Table with CANCAT key in MariaDB working in 10.0 but not later versions

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to upgrade from MariaDB 10.0 to 10.5 to use Galera Cluster. One of our tables has a key that the later versions won't accept. The error and table structure below.

Refactoring code is a last resort, so if there is a table definition change that can fix the problem that would be ***fantastic!***

Thank you!

Error

> ERROR 1901 (HY000) at line 40239: Function or expression
> 'concat(`tc_sequence_db_code`,`tc_sequence_prefix`,`tc_sequence_table_name`)'
> cannot be used in the GENERATED ALWAYS AS clause of `tc_sequence_id`

The table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `tc_sequence` (
  `tc_sequence_id` char(191) AS (concat(`tc_sequence_db_code`,`tc_sequence_prefix`,`tc_sequence_table_name`)),
  `tc_sequence_table_name` char(191) NOT NULL,
  `tc_sequence_db_code` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tc_sequence_prefix` char(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tc_sequence_next_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `dt_temp_id` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tc_sequence_trf_yn` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  UNIQUE KEY `tc_sequence_id` (`tc_sequence_id`),
  KEY `tc_sequence_table_name` (`tc_sequence_table_name`),
  KEY `dt_temp_id` (`dt_temp_id`),
  KEY `tc_sequence_trf_yn` (`tc_sequence_trf_yn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Try wrapping that entire `CONCAT` with `RTRIM()` to see if makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that clue helped. I haven't tried your suggestion but this did work:

concat(RTRIM(`tc_sequence_db_code`), RTRIM(`tc_sequence_prefix`), RTRIM(`tc_sequence_table_name`))

Much appreciated!!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have a complete answer/explanation, but that info was from [this MariaDB link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/), then search the page for `RTRIM` to see the info from the first search match down to _before_ the next **MySQL Compatibility Support** section.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Paul T for the clue that led to the solution. RTRIM around the CONCAT doesn't work but this does:

```
CREATE TABLE `tc_sequence` (
  `tc_sequence_id` char(191) AS (concat(RTRIM(`tc_sequence_db_code`),RTRIM(`tc_sequence_prefix`),RTRIM(`tc_sequence_table_name`))),
  `tc_sequence_table_name` char(191) NOT NULL,
  `tc_sequence_db_code` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tc_sequence_prefix` char(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tc_sequence_next_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `dt_temp_id` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tc_sequence_trf_yn` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  UNIQUE KEY `tc_sequence_id` (`tc_sequence_id`),
  KEY `tc_sequence_table_name` (`tc_sequence_table_name`),
  KEY `dt_temp_id` (`dt_temp_id`),
  KEY `tc_sequence_trf_yn` (`tc_sequence_trf_yn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Much appreciated Paul T!